# How to locate Google Chrome extension dir

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Hi i'm installing extensions by programmatically by a little c# program.

I just did see the software doesn't work on my friend.

i did see his chrome directory is not at %appdata% folder its at program files?

so how to find the real latest version of chrome directory for install plugins?

Google says

```
 Windows: 
 chrome_root\Application\chrome_version\Extensions\ 
 Example: c:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\6.0.422.0\Extensions\
```

but  how to find the chrome_root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Visit `chrome://version`.
2. Look at **Profile Path**.
3. Extensions can be found in the `Extensions` subdirectory of the path you found at the previous step.

[image: chrome://version]

You can also load the extension using the [`--load-extension`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension) flag:

```
chrome.exe --load-extension=path/to/extension
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended mechanism for installing extensions programmatically is [external extensions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html). It has the advantage of not depending on Chrome paths that might change, instead you can use a stable registry key or JSON file.