# Where is the extensions file for Chrome in OS X 10.7.5?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gwt, google-chrome-extension

Everybody seems to find it in this address "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions", however, for some reason I don't even have a "Google" folder in "Application Support". Anybody know of any other place where it might be or how to find it?

This is all part of my attempt to fix the problem Chrome 22 has with OS X that the extensions are not being loaded. More specifically, the GWT Developer plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `find /Users/username/ -type d -name Google  2> /dev/null` on Terminal application.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872962/944634

Comment: Thank you, that terminal command was quite useful to find the exact path.